# python runs differently with nohup

Tags: unix, python, nohup

I have a python package that runs fine when I launch as `python -m myproject`. However, when I launch as `nohup python -m myproject`, I get an `ImportError`. Furthermore, when I launch as `nohup python3 -m myproject`, it works normally.

It appears that the problem is that my `python` is aliased to python3 whereas the nohup is somehow using a non-default python. Why would this be?

Comment: Can you run the following commands in your shell and post their output?  `which python` and `type python`

Comment: @DavidGrayson `python` is an alias at `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  What is the output of the commands I mentioned above and what is the output of `readlink /usr/bin/python`?  What Linux/Unix distribution are you using and did you install Python using your distributions package manager?

Comment: type python >> python is aliased to `/usr/bin/python3'; which python >> /usr/bin/python; readlink /usr/bin/python >> python2.7; The fact that type python and the type of python point different directions is very odd to me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your *shell* (probably bash) has an alias assigned so that whenever you type `python` at the beginning of a command, it changes that to `/usr/bin/python3`.  It's hard for me to say why you have that alias.  It might be that your system administrator wants everyone to use Python 3 instead of Python 2 by default and this was an attempt to accomplish that.

Your `/usr/bin/python` is a symbolic link to a Python 2 binary.  This seems pretty normal; it is common on a lot of Linux distributions (such as Debian) for `python` to refer to Python 2, because Python 3 is not popular enough yet.  That is not always the case though; on Arch Linux, `python` refers to Python 3.

So, if I had to guess, I would say that the package manager of your system installed the symbolic link from `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2.7` because its policy is for people to use Python 2 by default.  But someone else who had some say in configuring your system decided that they want Python 3 to be used by default, so they installed this alias.

As you can see, the alias does not work all the time.  When you type `nohup python`, the shell does *not* expand your alias and instead just passes the string `python` as an argument to the `nohup` command.  The `nohup` command then has to figure out what `python` means, and all it does is look on your PATH; it does not know about your shell aliases.  It will find `/usr/bin/python` and end up running Python 2 for you.

You can read the manual of your shell to find out what files it runs on startup (e.g. .bashrc and things like that).  This will help you find out why your shell has that alias for Python 3.  Look for a line like this:

```
alias python=python3
```

You can read about the system's package manager to figure out how to look at what files belong to which packages, and that could help you figure out why there is a symbolic link for Python 2.  Just ask the package manager which package owns the `/usr/bin/python` link.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! I myself set up `alias python=python3` expecting that that would also make `/usr/bin/python` link to python3. Having now proved that I'm a menace to my system and also discovered PEP394, perhaps I'll just reset it to the original.

Answer (score -1):

It means you have installed lib in python2 not in python3.
if you install package like 
**sudo pip install**  then by default it installs in python2
but if you install like **sudo pip3 install**  then it installs in python3

you can use pip3.6 for python3.6 like wise.